# Keycloak can't access config when imported from external node library and redirect results in CORS errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keycloak

I built a library with custom components to be used in future projects. So I import the library in a bunch of other projects. The projects are usually bundled with a spring boot service that accesses other backend services.

[image]

These projects' App.js is being wrapped by a component that uses Keycloak under the hood.

[image]

This works perfectly if I start my application via `npm start` but I get a bunch of CORS errors if I start the application as package (in Intellij). (starting the application by `npm start` I get port 3000, but the production build is on 8441)

I noticed that Keycloak can't find the config and that may be the problem, since when I use `run build` everything goes into the `dist` folder except everything that's not under `src` folder.

[image]

I tried adding the config as a js object in my service like this

[image]

But then I got this

[image]

I also noticed that the redirect goes to `localhost:port/keycloak.json` and not to `localhost:port/something/keycloak.json` So essentially the router basename is missing in the redirect.

Anyhow, is there a way to include the config in the library, or to access the config from the project in that I imported my library AND not miss `something` in the redirect (`localhost:port/something/keycloak.json`)?

I already tried including the config in a folder in the library but the redirect path was still incorrect.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible you're forgetting to pass "clientId" in config?

Comment: Hey - I can't find anything by googling the client id issue ("keycloak clientId missing"). It's frustrating.

Comment: Nothing fancy here, simply pass your `clientId` in the config. Few more things, I think that javascript keycloak config accepts attributes in camelCase: `ssl-required` should be `sslRequired` and so on, plus `authServerUrl` should only be passed as `url`

Comment: Alright - everything is in camelCase and added the clientId and I could login. But no rest calls work - everything results in CORS error. I added a screenshot to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone reading this. Make sure your `application.yaml` and `application-dev.yml` are configured correctly. Under `project.servers.frontend.baseUrl` I had `localhost:3000` while my frontend-backend is on 8441 - results in CORS errors (I start my project by "Run as Package" which runs on 8441 - this is both frontend (React) and frontendBacken (Spring Boot)).

[image]

[image]